# Как преобразовать строку с HTML-разметкой в DOM-объект?

Tags: javascript, классы

Вот у меня есть класс, который создает карточку с песней для плейлиста:

```
`use strict`

class Card {
    constructor({ artist, song }) {
        this.artist = artist
        this.song = song
        this.card_item = this.create(this.artist, this.song)

        this.like = this.like.bind(this)
        this.remove = this.delete.bind(this)


        // this.card_item.querySelector('.fa-trash').addEventListener('click', this.delete)
        // this.card_item.querySelector('.fa-hear').addEventListener('click', this.like)

    }

    create(artist, song) {
        return `
            <div class="card">
                <span class="card__artist">${artist}</span>
                <span class="card__song">${song}</span>
                <button class="song__like"></button>
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </div>
        `
    }

    like(event) {
        event.target.classList.toggle('heart_black')
    }

    delete(event) {
        const card = event.target.closest('.card')
        card.classList.add('hide')

        event.target.querySelector('.fa-heart').removeEventListener('click', this.like)
        event.target.querySelector('.fa-trash').removeEventListener('click', this.delete)
    }
}
```

В конструкторе закомментированы 2 строки где я пытаюсь на кнопки карточки повесить обработчики событий (методы класса). Причина: интерпретатор ругается и говорит, что "querySelector is not a function".

Похоже, потому, что в `this.card_item` хранится строка с разметкой, а `querySelector` можно применить только к DOM-обхекту.

Как мне доработать метод 'create' чтобы все заработало нормально?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create(artist, song) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card">
            <span class="card__artist">${artist}</span>
            <span class="card__song">${song}</span>
            <button class="song__like"></button>
            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </div>
    `;
    return div.firstElementChild;
}
```

Comment: Очень вам спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>";
var element = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml");
```

Comment: Парсер возвращает документ. Нужно дописать .firstElementChild в конце.